# VPN worked with Vista client, but breaks with Win7 client

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-7, vpn, netbios

I have a VPN with WinServer2003 on the host side and Vista (x64) as the client.

The Vista client (192.168.0.nnn) connects daily to the VPN to backup all the machines on the host side (10.1.nnn.nnn). This has been working fine for about 3 years.

I'm trying to replace the Vista client machine with a newer machine running Win7 (also x64).

The Win7 machine connects to the VPN OK, but can't ping any of the host-side machines by name (by NetBIOS name, that is).  It can ping them by IP address fine (ping 10.1.0.94).

I still have the old Vista client running - it still works fine ("ping wilkins" works on the Vista client, but not on the Win7 client).

To make it a little stranger, the Win7 client box WAS able to ping host-side machines OK when I accidentally had it mis-configured with "Use default gateway on remote network" checked on the VPN network connection. Then it had no problem seeing the host-side machines by name.

However, I noticed that *all* Internet access from the client was going over the VPN link, which is not what I wanted (the Internet connection on the host side is slow).  So I unchecked that box; now I can ping only by numeric IP, not by NetBIOS address. This is not good, because the IP addresses on the host side are not known to the client (they're dynamic); so I need to address them by name.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which VPN Software are you using?